# Javascript formula validator

Tags: javascript, parsing

Is there a way in javscript, which can validate formula on data types and not with actual values.

For example, take ceil example.

```
Math.ceil(input)
```

This function takes number as input parameter and it fails input is a string.

For such kinds of formulas is there any validator that can validate based on datatypes.I need something like below:

```
var a= 1.0;
var b="aaa";
var out1 = Math.ceil(a); // works, out1=1
var out2= Math.ceil(b); // return NaN

var ret1 = validate("Math.ceil(a)"); // should return true
var ret2 = validate("Math.ceil(b)"); // should return false
```

I dont have actual value of variables.Only datatypes are known in advance.Value of these variables will be replaced in later stage and I want to validate these expressions based on datatypes.Also note that this is only one function , I need to do this for all math functions.

Comment: what.. should it return true for string `aaa`

Comment: sorry..it should return false for string

Comment: if you want to check the type of variable you have http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_typeof.asp

Comment: What you are essentially talking about is type hinting in JavaScript. There were some attempts to make that a thing in JavaScript but the concept never really took off since JavaScript is dynamically typed in nature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) and use a try/catch as a garantee.

```
function validate(formula) {
    try {
        var ret = eval(formula); 
        if(ret && ret != "NaN") {
            return true;
        } 
        return false;
    } catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2f1nwcg8/)

Comment: I prefer not to use the exception handling here, because the expression must be correct (in order to execute) in order to determine if the EXECUTION of the expression returned a value or not.

Comment: That's what the function does! check if the EXECUTION has an return and if this return is not NaN. The exception handle is just a way to garantee that you code will not break if something goes wrong. Because you are using eval

Comment: The eval method may fail to execute the expression, so a false-return-value will be returned although the expression was not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function as a start point

```
function evaluate(expression) {
    if (!(expression && (typeof(expression) == "string")))
        throw "invalid expression";

    var evaluatedValue = eval(expression);

    return !!evaluatedValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to parse the desired data type using this function, then proceed from there:

```
function testType(value, expected) {
    if (typeof(value) == expected) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You use it like this:

```
if(testType(a,"number")) {
    // your code here
}
```

But... maybe you're forgetting to take care of some exceptions, like:

0/0 == NaN;
1/0 == infinite;

If you want your formulas to work, you'll need to handle those exceptions as well, adding `isFinite(value)` and `!isNaN(value)` as well in this function.